# Why is an extra pixel added to firefox elements when I use `line-height: 1` in my reset?

Tags: css, firefox

I use this reset.

```
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: 1;
}
hr {display: none}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {content: ''}
blockquote, q {quotes: "" ""}
ul {list-style-type: none}
ol {list-style-type: decimal}
a {text-decoration: none}

.clear {clear: both}
```

The problem is that as long as I use line-height: 1 I see an extra pixel that does not go away no matter what I do in my block links even I tried setting height, line-height, font-size for it. nothing works. Please tell me what's going on with firefox line-height.

This is my css.

```
.tag {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #555;
    text-transform: lowercase;
        padding: 3px 6px;
}
```

Pretty simple yea? Seems not. Firefox will create a pixel on top of text I can clearly see it its not balanced even though I set top and bottom padding the same. Someone tell me why this happens, if I remove the line-height: 1 from my reset a whole lot of other things get screwed up.

Comment: Did you try `line-height:normal;` or `line-height:100%;`? Can you post a jsfiddle example?

Comment: line-height:normal to .tag fixed it. Please please tell me why !! :) i never added something like that.. but please explain to me why did this fix the extra pixel?

Comment: I've added an answer with that in it. Speculatively, it's possible that the multiplication of 1 against your font size caused the extra pixel somehow, but I'm not sure. Do you have non-integer font-sizes (ie. `1.4em`)?

Comment: No, i am using pixels for font-sizes, heights, etc. thats why I was confused :S anyway, no prob i will use that fix when needed

Comment: Well either way, I'm glad it works for you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `line-height: normal;`

This tells it to keep the same height as the text (which would seem to be the same as `line-height:1` but perhaps firefox treats it differently).

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, I see no space using your CSS above, im using firefox 3.6.13

Maybe see if you can recreate a mock up of your issue on JSbin?

http://jsbin.com/ajinu3

Comment: line-height: normal fixed it. Do not know why, but I am so confused.

Comment: Great to know it's fixed now :)